# Unknown files inside the root folder, filename starting with ".reaper"

Tags: malware, files

I **previewed (not downloaded)** by mistake today a malicious PDF on the Gmail app with Adobe Reader app, and I already inspected the phone for malware, uninstalled the Adobe Reader app in case it was exploited, removed all Gmail cache (including content from `com.google.android.gm`), reviewed the apps, etc.

But during this phone inspection, there are files in the root of my phone called:

- **.reaper_activate_file.txt** with content `{"is_reset":"1","time_stamp":"1649891130602"}`
- **.reaper_action_file.txt** with content `1649891130602`
- a file called **.turing.dat**

that I don't recognize.

I keep deleting these files and they keep showing up. I'm not sure if these files were there before or if they were generated after the incident today.

Has someone seen these files before? Is there any app that can show me which app generated these files?  If someone here is familiar with these 2 files and knows where they are coming from, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Have the same 3 files on my Infinix Hot 10s / Android 11.
Plz keep me informed.